# Lack of ideas for vectorization of text feature (music genre)

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization, word2vec

I'm in the process of creating a predictive model of track popularity. One of the features that I have is music genre. The variable contains many unique, but similar values, for instance: 'contemporary country', 'country pop', 'trap', 'lo-fi trap'. **I'm looking for a ways to represent that column numerically**.

I would like to create 1D embeddings for my the music genre variable based on audio features of tracks belonging to a particular genre. Is that actually possible ?

I'd be super grateful for any kind of assistance with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Treating the genres as tokens, and training a vector-per-genre, should be possible.

For training, you'd need "texts" that use the different genres together - these could be the multiple genres users have assigned to a single track, or the sequences-of-genres within a certain user's listening-history, or the sequences-of-genres within a certain artist's works, etc.

And, I suspect this approach could work fairly well, successfully placing genres into a coordinate space where their relative distances/directions to each other resemble human judgements. These "dense embeddings" could then be used as inputs to other downstream ML techniques.

Some thoughts that may help:

- For a good dense embedding, you'll want the space dimensionality to be much smaller than the count of unique tokens. That is, much smaller in number-of-continuous dimensions than the "one-hot" encoding would be. So you probably **don't** want to collapse related genres (like `low-fi trap` into `trap`) - that'd be throwing away potentially useful subtleties in the data, even if they're noisy, when the point of *2vec training is to be able to learn/numerically-model such subtleties (as long as there are enough examples of contextual use).
- When training on data that isn't truly natural language, and for specific predictive purposes, it becomes more likely that training parameters far from the usual defaults may be optimal – once you have a repeatable way to score different models for your purposes. (For example, there's a exponentiation parameter used in the negative-sampling that was fixed at `0.75` in most word2vec implementations - but a [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04212) suggests very-different values may be noticeably better in recommendation-applications. So, it's been made specifiable in recent versions of the Python `gensim` library.)

Answer (score 2):

When converting categorical data to numerical data, we have two options:

1. One-Hot Vector
2. Entity Embedding

One-Hot Vector is used when the number of unique columns is small (few hundreds). Entity Embeddings are used if we have a large number of unique features (thousands). Embeddings map features into a 1D vector and give an idea about how close (or far) features are in proximity. In your case, country and country-pop will be closer related than country and trap. It sounds like you have a large number of unique features for 'genre'. Hence I would chose an embedding technique.

As gojomo pointed out in his answer, you will need a corpus for training that uses the different genres together and develop a scoring system. After training your model, you can use the output of your training further downstream with other ML techniques.

Comment: I like the idea of training 1D embeddings. I can't wait to try it out when I get back to home. Do you think it would be possible to create embeddings based on audio features (like instrumentalness, acousticness, speechiness etc.) rather than text corpus ?

Comment: That should be possible if the audio features have a high enough correlation with genre. Intuitively they should, but you should check that the predictive power of audio features is high enough to tell what genre you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

also this is maybe not the optimal approach, you could use a `text.preprocessing` from `keras`.
it works like the following:

```
max_words = 1000
tokenize = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, char_level=False)
tokenize.fit_on_texts(train_text) # fit tokenizer to our training text data
x_train = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(train_text)
x_test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(test_text)
```

the output looks like this:

```
array([[0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

you will have a lot of features, but even when you use 'normal' ML algorithm, they will recognize the unimportance from the feature: `lo-fi`for example.

But the part to map it to general genres before can be very complicated.